# How do I see everything stored in Office.context.document.settings?

Tags: excel, office-js

Looking through [the docs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/settings.md), I wasn't able to find a way to view everything currently stored in settings. I'm trying to debug some memory issues, and I'm worried that giant objects have been stored in the document settings (potentially from other add-ins that have worked on this same workbook).

Is there a way to see everything stored in Office.context.document.settings without using the .get method (which requires you to know the name of the property you want)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which host are you looking for? For Word and Excel, there is an API to get all settings. For Word, `document.settings` and for Excel use `workbook.settings`. Other hosts don't support this API.

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const settings = context.workbook.settings.load();
        settings.load("items");
        await context.sync();
        for (let i = 0; i < settings.items.length; i++) {
             console.log(JSON.stringify(settings.items[i])) + "\n";
        }
    });
```

For Word, just replace context.workbook with context.document.

Comment: Works perfectly. Any way to see the settings in the Excel UI?

Comment: No - it's not a UI feature. It's just stored in the document.

Answer (score 2):

It also wouldn't help you here since it also only surfaces settings from the *current* add-in. Any settings created by other add-ins are inaccessible from yours.

Your best bet is to decompress the `.docx` file (it's just a Zip file) and inspect the contents directly. The settings are stored as XML in the `\xl\webextensions` folder.

Comment: Didn't realize it was add-in specific.  Thanks!